# Navbar toggle button centering

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap navbar toggle button floating towards center when collapsed and then returning to its proper position on the right when clicked.

I've tried to copy the code from the bootstrap website again but to no avail, the button still floats towards the center.

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png">
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon">      
</span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="day_map.html">Daytime Map</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="night-map.html">Nighttime Map<a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

I'd like the toggle button to remain on the right when it's collapsed.

Comment: remove ml-auto from navbar

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that but it only changed the alignment. The toggler still floats to the center when collapsed.

Comment: Just rearrange the order of your elements, so toggle is at the end. That will work. [Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz589xow/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there, just change the order of your elements, putting the toggle component as the final item, and it will display on the far right.

**Here's the working code:**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
<img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/bootstrap-4.svg" height="30">
  </a>
    
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="day_map.html">Daytime Map</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="night-map.html">Nighttime Map<a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
    
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

</nav>
```

I also refined your code a bit, you don't need your `.container-fluid` wrapper div for the navbar.

Reference: [Bootstrap navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)